# how to pass each shell parameter in new line

Tags: linux, shell, aix

I had a shell script that takes 3 parameters

```
test.sh a b c
```

I want to give each parameter in a new line

some thing like this :

```
test.sh a
        b
        c
```

i am on AIX
Thanks.

Comment: please explain a little bit of `why` you need to do this. Just for formatting? (Are you an SQL coder at heart?) . The solution below is the best you can do, given your basic problem definition. OR Are `a, b, c` really place holders for complex argument generation processes like calling scripts that caluclate values? Good luck!

Comment: For formatting .I am passing really a large string parameters . Thanks for your suggestion to add that to a variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just put `\` at the end of line, it "escapes" the meaning of the character following it, which in this case is a newline.

```
test.sh a \
        b \
        c
```

Comment: Correct. Look out: no space after the \ and no \ after the last parameter.

Comment: you suggestion helped me Walter. Thanks